# How do I get the size of a merged Excel cell

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm trying to write code in C# to parse a large Excel sheet that wasn't really designed with automation in mind, and it's full of merged cells.  Many times I know the location of one cell, but need to get the text of another cell a few cells away, but those cells may be merged and span multiple normal cells.  How do I get the size of a merged cell in number of cells?

Also, how can I get the location of a cell a certain number of cells away, when the cells in between are merged?  I tried Excel.Range.Offset, but that seems to be only counting real cells, not merged ones (so if there's a 4-wide merged cell in between, offset 2 will take me to the middle of that cell, rather than the one next to it).

Comment: If you've tried something, please post your code and state what you expect it to do and how it's not doing it.

Comment: Why do you need to get the size of the merged cells in C# - why not get the actual cell distance and use that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I need to be able to find a cell, say, 2 cells away where all the cells may or may not be merged.  If my range is a merged cell, if I use cell.Offset[0,1], I will automatically move to the next cell, but if I use Offset[0,2], I may not move to the cell after that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to determine size of merged area:

```
    var activeSheet = this.Application.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
    if (activeSheet != null)
    {
        var activeCell = activeSheet.Cells[2, 2];
        if (activeCell.MergeCells)
        {
            if (activeCell.MergeArea != null)
            {
                dynamic mergeAreaValue2 = activeCell.MergeArea.Value2;
                object[,] vals = mergeAreaValue2 as object[,];

                if (vals != null)
                {                            
                    int rows = vals.GetLength(0);
                    int cols = vals.GetLength(1);
                }                        
            }
        }
    }
```

Assumption is that `Cells[2,2]` is left upper corner of merged area. In variables rows and cols will be the amount of rows and columns in merged area - so this is an answer to the question how many rows or columns should be skipped.